# How to compute frequency of one variable in data frame conditional on another

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with a mutation annotation file:

```r
dim(df_maf)
## [1] 3906  136
```

I want to know the number of unique values of the variable `Tumor_Sample_Barcode` in each level of the variable `Variant_Classification`. I have tried using `table` like so:

```r
table(df_maf$Variant_Classification)
```

```
       Frame_Shift_Del        Frame_Shift_Ins           In_Frame_Del           In_Frame_Ins 
                   171                    125                     16                      2 
     Missense_Mutation      Nonsense_Mutation       Nonstop_Mutation            Splice_Site 
                  2529                    877                      2                    182 
Translation_Start_Site 
                     2
```

But that does not give counts of unique values of `Tumor_Sample_Barcode`.

One approach that I can imagine is to split the data frame into subsets corresponding to the unique values of `Variant_Classification` then calculate lengths, but that doesn't seems to be very efficient.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Do you need `table(df_maf[c("Sample", "Variant_Classification")])`

Comment: Error in `[.data.table`(RBM10_df_2, c("Tumor_Sample_Barcode", "Variant_Classification")) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: I am getting this error by using your solution @akrun

Comment: I thought it is a data.frame.  You may need `table(as.data.frame(df_maf)[c("Sample", "Variant_Classification")])`

Comment: class(RBM10_df_2)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

Comment: Same error persists unfortunately by adding as.data.frame too

Comment: Can you please use `dput` to show a small reproducible example and your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have this df 2 samples and 3 variants,

```
df=data.frame(sample=c("id1","id1","id1","id2","id2"),variant=c("V1","V1","V2","V1","V3"))

df

  sample variant
1    id1      V1
2    id1      V1
3    id1      V2
4    id2      V1
5    id2      V3
```

to see how many samples are in each type of variant :

```
df%>%
  group_by(variant)%>%
  summarise(n_samples=length(unique(sample)))

  variant n_samples
  <chr>       <int>
1 V1              2
2 V2              1
3 V3              1
```